# Images in Individual Grids in GridView in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a GridView. On clicking each individual grid, I need a picture to appear in the grid I click. My code for the same is below:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
            ImageView grid = (ImageView) v;
            grid.setClickable(false);
            grid.setImageResource(R.drawable.skin_x);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But my code crashes, when I click the grid. Is there any logical error in the above code? Can someone please suggest a good solution for my solution. I am a beginner in android and so please don't be hard on me. Thanks in advance!
My logcat error report is below:

```
08-01 09:43:23.200: E/InputEventReceiver(783): Exception dispatching input event.
08-01 09:43:23.200: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at com.example.ultimatetictactoe.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:53)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3435)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271) 
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-01 09:43:23.240: E/MessageQueue-JNI(783):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 09:43:23.250: D/AndroidRuntime(783): Shutting down VM
08-01 09:43:23.250: W/dalvikvm(783): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.example.ultimatetictactoe.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:53)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3435)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-01 09:43:23.290: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the layout code for the Grid Item or the crash log

Comment: You're casting `v` once into an `ImageView` and once into a `TextView`, so there's definitely something wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageView grid = (ImageView) v;

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
```

This means that `v` is a `TextView`.

So the layout your are using for the grid item is just a `TextView`.

You should change that into a `Layout` containing an `ImageView` and a `TextView`.

For example:

**Grid item layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OnClickListener**

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);;
        image.setClickable(false);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.skin_x);
        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

a View what you get in onItemClick method isn't an ImageView, you should get imageView from that view.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
        int position, long id) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_image_id);
        image.setClickable(false);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.skin_x);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should put a corect id into findViewById method, R.id.grid_image_id is just an example

Comment: Ya i know. Doesnt work still. Problem i think is that we cannot typecast a View into an ImageView.

Comment: the proble i gues that there is no ImageView with your id in grid item. How your grid item layout looks like?